# How to update Android Studio .jar file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to update my Android Studio from v0.1 to v0.2.5 and download the .jar file [from here](http://www.softgozar.com/WebPage/Download.aspx?SoftwareId=2436&Title=Google-Android-Studio-0.2.5-Build-130.782403).

How to reload .jar file in Android Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Note: There is not a patch update available from 0.1.9 to 0.2. To update from Android Studio 0.1.x to 0.2.x, you must install a new Android Studio bundle from this page. The reason for that is that we have made changes to the bundled SDK such that it includes a pre-configured local Maven repository which can serve up the v4 support library and which is required for creating new projects.

From http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Revisions

So why not downloading a new version of Android Studio?

**Update**: If you can't update by network. Try this:

> java -classpath /path/to/AI-130.687321-130.692269-patch-unix.jar  com.intellij.updater.Runner install $PWD

From https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56068

Comment: what about v0.2?? I mean if I install v0.2 , how can I apply this patch?

Comment: java -classpath patch.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install <Android studio diretory> $PWD

worked for me (specific android studio directory)

Comment: On Linux I had to run `java -classpath /tmp/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio com.intellij.updater.Runner install android-studio/` where `android-studio/` was my Android Studio installation directory.  The update downloaded the patch but never ran it.  I had to run it manually.

Comment: To help other mac users, the android studio directory or $PWD is `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/`

Answer (score 2):

Running Windows 8 (as a local admin), I needed patch from a reasonably recent version to 0.9.2. However I ran into the "unable to delete files" issue when trying to patch directly from within Android Studio (running as admin). After doing the 100 MEG download twice (Aussie slow Internet), I needed something smarter. Follows is what worked for me (your mileage may vary):

1. I found the download JAR in my C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp directory. It had a strange extension, but was obviously the patch file from the files date/time stamp.
2. So I copied this file into a nice directory (c:\temp), renaming the extension to ".jar"
3. My install of Android Studio is in c:\program files (x86)\Android\android-studio - so using Windows Explorer I gave the "everyone" user full control of the folder and all sub-folders. Yes I know this is bad practice on a prod server but hear me out.
4. I open up a command window in c:\temp and entered the following command line (where the .jar file name was the JAR file I found and renamed):

   **java -classpath jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio.jar install "c:\program files (x86)\Android\android-studio"**
5. This commenced the patch which completed successfully. Giving "everyone" full control meant that the delete operations completed okay - at least that's my belief. I remove the everyone access after the patch completed (I bet you thought I'd forget to do this!).
6. Started up Android Studio and checked the version which is now current - PHEW!

Best of luck with manually patching on Windows 8. I really love Android Studio, but its definitely on the clunky side in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the new jar file to app\libs folder.
Make sure in your build.gradle (app), you import the file under dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation files ('libs/myfile.jar')
```

Do a File | Invalidate caches / restart to refresh the jar file.