# I get java core dumped error while updating android studio

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to update Android-Studio, and I've downloaded the `.jar` file using firefox but have a problem.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457818/how-to-update-android-studio-with-jar-file) link and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022886/how-to-update-android-studio-with-jar-file) to update it, but this error occures:

```
$ java -classpath Downloads/AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338-183.6156.11.34.5522156-patch-unix.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install /home/user/Andriod/android-studio

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0368d74009, pid=13991, tid=13992
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/user/core.13991)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/user/hs_err_pid13991.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
[1]    13991 abort (core dumped)  java -classpath  com.intellij.updater.Runner install
```

`/home/user/Andriod/android-studio` is my android-studio installation path.

What should I do?

Comment: debug the error, open the file located at and search for fatal reason for the cause  /home/user/hs_err_pid13991.log